# Problem with authorization of any action that requires my password

Tags: 11.10, password

I use Ubuntu 11.10.
After successful obtain of all available updates I have a problem with authorization of any action that requires my password. I cannot use Ubuntu Software Center, Terminal...
My password input is correct because I use it to log in to the system.
Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Comment: Does you password contain non-ascii characters?

Comment: Do you realise that (because of security) your password does not appear in the Terminal? Just type your password and hit enter... If you are having problems with Software Center, have you tried a different Package Manager e.g. Synaptic? You could also try a blunderbuss approach by trying these commands in a Terminal, one-by-one: sudo dpkg --configure -a,
sudo apt-get -f install,
sudo apt-get --fix-missing install,
sudo apt-get update,
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade,
sudo apt-get clean,
sudo apt-get autoremove,
sudo apt-get update

Comment: Yes, I realize that. I tried everything that you mentioned, but I still get error message that my password is incorrect (even after successful login with that same password).

Comment: Maybe you are/were using more than one keyboard layout...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I found that I changed hostname in /etc/hostname but not in the rest of places. So check your hostname. If it is not problem with hostname try to remove any asking for password: Complete tutorial for removing password for programs and actions is here: http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/06/run-programs-and-actions-without.html